# Compound Sentence with Questioning Conjunction

Tags: conjunctions

Of the two sentences below, which one is correct and what is the related grammatical concept?

> 1. I can't figure out where the above identity comes from.
> 2. I can't figure out where does the above identity come from.

Comment: 1. is correct. The expression "where the above identity comes from" is a subordinate interrogative clause (embedded question) functioning as complement of "out". Subordinate interrogative do not (normally) have subject-auxiliary inversion and hence 2., which does have inversion, is incorrect. The meaning is "I can't figure out the answer to the question 'Where does the above identity come from?"'.

Comment: @BillJ Your comment contains every point that I need. Why don't you leave it as an answer so that I could mark it as an answer to the OP?

Answer (score 1):

[1] *I can't figure out [where the above identity comes from].*

[2] *I can't figure out [where does the above identity come from].*

[1] is correct. The expression "where the above identity comes from" is a subordinate interrogative clause (embedded question) functioning as complement of "figure out". Subordinate interrogatives do not (normally) have subject-auxiliary inversion and hence [2], which does contain inversion, is incorrect.

The meaning is "I can't figure out the answer to the question 'Where does the above identity come from?"'